# Swing - How to create a Jbutton that adds e.g Boats to a fleet

Tags: java, swing

For my Project i have to be able to add/remove boats to a fleet.I would like to use a Jbutton for that. I have 10 buttons which 5 are boats and i want to add them to fleet. Code for 1 of 10 jbutton using addActionListener() the thing im trying to do is that if a press a boat button it will print out in a textarea one after another (like a receipt). i have the same code structer for all buttons my second question is-Is there a way of making the code a bit shorter.

```
 button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                addBoat.setVisible(true);
                button6.setVisible(true);
                button7.setVisible(true);
                button8.setVisible(true);
                button9.setVisible(true);
                button10.setVisible(true);
                text.setText(john.getText());
                text.validate();
                    okButton.setVisible(true);


            }
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is probably the simplest way that I know of. The only way to make it slightly shorter would be to make an array that includes all of the buttons then make a for loop that does that for you. An example of setting up the array would be:

```
JButton[] boats = new JButton[5];
```

And then the for loop would be:

```
for(int n = 0; n < boats.length; n++){
boats[n].setVisible(true);
}
```

The only thing I left out is actually adding the JButtons to the array, but this should do it. In the future I would recommend using more helpful names for your buttons to make it easier for others to read your code.